# How to set text in edittext which should not editable

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-edittext, textview

I am using an `EditText` displaying `TextView` on the left. This shouldn't be editable.

My Question is how to put `TextView` in an `EditText`?  How it is  possible?

Actually I want like this:

[image: TextView in EditeText]

Below is xml code.

```
<EditText
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:text="user@gmail.com"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="*Mobile number"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:gravity="end" />
```

Comment: So you want a both `*Mobile number` and after that the option to input the number?

Comment: yes exactly @grrigore

Comment: You should use `TextView` for the first one and `EditText` for the second one. There is no need to try to make `EditText` not editable because that's what `TextView` it's for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My Question is how to put TextView in EditText?

Not Possible, because This is not Built in behavior of `EditText`

> How is it possible?

You can use a **`TextView`**  and **`EditText`** in a  `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="horizontal"`

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/colorBackgroundFloating"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Enter Name" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="123"
            android:padding="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Enter Name" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="123"
            android:padding="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Enter Name" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="123"
            android:padding="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make your edittext non-editable using below properties:

```
android:inputType="none"
```

if you want to do it programmatically

```
EditText editText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourid);
editText.setEnabled(false);
editText.setKeyListener(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am totally agree with @Nilesh Rathod just want to propose that to move this `LinearLayout` in a separate file and reuse it in multiple places like `Fragment`